# Deleting the command after embed has been executed

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make it to where when the embed for example below is executed, the `?ra1` message from the user is deleted. Thanks for any help.

```py
@client.command()
async def ra1(ctx):

    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
        title="RIDEALONG 1 REQUEST",
        description=str(ctx.author.mention) + " IS REQUESTING THEIR FIRST RIDEALONG IN SERVER !"
    )
    embed.add_field(name="For CDTOs", value="Please message the user to accept their RA request. Please delete their message once the ridealong has been completed.", inline=False)
    embed.timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=7200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `await ctx.message.delete()` in order to delete the message that triggered the command.

```py
@client.command()
async def ra1(ctx):

    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
        title="RIDEALONG 1 REQUEST",
        description=str(ctx.author.mention) + " IS REQUESTING THEIR FIRST RIDEALONG IN SERVER !"
    )
    embed.add_field(name="For CDTOs", value="Please message the user to accept their RA request. Please delete their message once the ridealong has been completed.", inline=False)
    embed.timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=7200)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

## References

- [`discord.Message.delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete)
- [`Context.message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.message)

Answer (score 1):

`Context` has the attribute `message` which you can delete

```py
await ctx.message.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple infact its just using `await ctx.message.delete()`

Implemented inside of your code:

```
@client.command()
async def ra1(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
        title="RIDEALONG 1 REQUEST",
        description=str(ctx.author.mention) + " IS REQUESTING THEIR FIRST RIDEALONG IN SERVER !"
    )
    embed.add_field(name="For CDTOs", value="Please message the user to accept their RA request. Please delete their message once the ridealong has been completed.", inline=False)
    embed.timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=7200)
```